# SQL query as string in JSON file

Tags: sql, arrays, json

It is possible to store SQL query in JSON array of objects?? Because when i have something like this:

```
[{
        "id": "1",
        "query": "SELECT ID FROM table"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "query": "SELECT ID FROM table"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "query": "SELECT USER FROM table"
    }
]
```

JSON file in VSCode is ok no error it is getting nasty when i want to store complex queries with joins etc.

for example this query even if i format it correctly it will generate error in JSON file about formatting

(just example i not it is not valid)

```
SELECT user, id, , count(price) as numrev
  FROM price
  where id = 1 and user = 0 
  group by user, id, price
```

that it can't be stored in string

Answer (score -2):

It is bit easy to do, but requires on extra step.

1. Simply convert/encode you raw SQL queries in base64 text.
2. Decode the text before you execute the queries in you code.

If the JSON file is created automatically by a program/code

All most all programming languages proved base64 encode / decode functions as part of the core if not download  compatible package / library to achieve this automation

```js
var queries = [{
    "id": "1",
    "query": "U0VMRUNUIElEIEZST00gdGFibGU="
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "query": "U0VMRUNUIElEIEZST00gdGFibGU="
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "query": "U0VMRUNUIFVTRVIgRlJPTSB0YWJsZQ=="
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "query": "U0VMRUNUIHVzZXIsIGlkLCAsIGNvdW50KHByaWNlKSBhcyBudW1yZXYKICBGUk9NIHByaWNlCiAgd2hlcmUgaWQgPSAxIGFuZCB1c2VyID0gMCAKICBncm91cCBieSB1c2VyLCBpZCwgcHJpY2U="
  }
];

for (i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
  console.log("id = " + queries[i].id + ", query = " + atob(queries[i].query));
}
```

when you parse you JSON array make sure to decode before you execute the SQL queries.

let me know this one helped you.. ☺☻☺

FYI , refer [http://www.utilities-online.info/base64/](http://www.utilities-online.info/base64/#.XNdJBKThWM8)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTkXf.png)